# Got a list of dictionaries and i only need 1 value

Tags: python, google-api

I got this list and i need to put the string "13 Nov 2018 06:42:48" in a variable

{u'name': u'Date', u'value': u'Tue, 13 Nov 2018 06:42:48 -0800'}, 
{u'name': u'From', u'value': u'Email Test '}, {u'name': u'To', u'value': u'joao.testmailbox@gmail.com'}, 
{u'name': u'Subject', u'value': u'IsMyEmailWorking.com - Test ID [55239f16-4185-4255-8404-47d280b2cfb7]'}, {u'name': u'Content-Type', u'value': u'text/plain; charset="utf-8"'}, 
{u'name': u'Content-Transfer-Encoding', u'value': u'quoted-printable'}]

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
ls = [{u'name': u'Date', u'value': u'Tue, 13 Nov 2018 06:42:48 -0800'},
      {u'name': u'From', u'value': u'Email Test '},
      {u'name': u'To', u'value': u'joao.testmailbox@gmail.com'},
      {u'name': u'Subject', u'value': u'IsMyEmailWorking.com - Test ID [55239f16-4185-4255-8404-47d280b2cfb7]'},
      {u'name': u'Content-Type', u'value': u'text/plain; charset="utf-8"'},
      {u'name': u'Content-Transfer-Encoding', u'value': u'quoted-printable'}]

date_variable = ls[0]['value']
# date_variable = "Tue, 13 Nov 2018 06:42:48 -0800"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following code:

```
ls = {u'name': u'Date', u'value': u'Tue, 13 Nov 2018 06:42:48 -0800'}, {u'name': u'From', u'value': u'Email Test '}, {u'name': u'To', u'value': u'joao.testmailbox@gmail.com'}, {u'name': u'Subject', u'value': u'IsMyEmailWorking.com - Test ID [55239f16-4185-4255-8404-47d280b2cfb7]'}, {u'name': u'Content-Type', u'value': u'text/plain; charset="utf-8"'}, {u'name': u'Content-Transfer-Encoding', u'value': u'quoted-printable'}
data= ls[0]
day =data['value']
info=day[5:25]
print(info)
```

additionnal info : 
if you want the current date and time you can simply extract the info from the following :

```
import time
info = time.ctime()
```

You know how to do the rest.
Cheers